# No access to static resource when I change url-pattern to "/"

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, web

I wrote an application in Java with Spring framework. In web.xml I define servlet mapping and when I use "/" pattern I get nice url for example "/login","/register" it's fine but  access to static resource like .jpg or .css is blocked. If I use pattern like "*.html" resources works fine but I don't want url like "/login.html".

How to solve this?

Comment: There are several ways to do this. You could set the pattern to something like `/app` and keep your static resources in appropriate folders that don't collide with the path. Another way is to make a servlet filter and intercept/forward requests accordingly to your liking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a resource handler in your dispatcher servlet configuration.  This will allow all requests that have `/resources/` within the url pattern to avoid being routed by the dispatcher servlet.  When using this configuration you will need to place all of your static resources within a directory named resources.

```xml
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

[Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources)

Comment: Only I had add "<mvc:annotation-driven/>" becouse resources works but url no.